# How to hide a div if no checkbox is selected jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, hide

If no checkbox is selected, how do I .slideUp that parent div?

```
if ($("input:checkbox:not(:checked)")) {
    $("#parentOfParentDiv").slideUp();
// this should slide up the entire parent div IF NONE is selected, doesnt work       
    } else {
   $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").closest('div').slideUp();
//this should slideUp all the divs that are NOT checked, this works
}
```

Comment: Can you post sample`HTML` structure?

Comment: You should check the `length` of the collection. `$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)")` returns an object which is a truthy value in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this:

```
if (!$(":checkbox").is(":checked")) {
    $("#parentOfParentDiv").slideUp();
} else {   $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").closest('div').slideUp(); }
```

Comment: forgot to add `!`, now added

Comment: Thank you, i used this and now it works :) awesome quick reply

Comment: @user3712713 click on tick mark which you find in my answer

Comment: Thanks Amit, marked. Other answers helped also but i feel that this is easier to remember

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of checked checkboxes

```
if ($("input:checkbox:checked").length >0) {
     $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").closest('div').slideUp();  
} else {
     $("#parentOfParentDiv").slideUp();  
}
```

Comment: Thank you, quick reply, helped me out. I didnt realise that length works for non-text fields oto

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you should be checking the length of checked checkboxes:

```
if (!$("input:checkbox:checked").length) { // nothing is checked
  $("#parentOfParentDiv").slideUp();  
} else {
   $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").closest('div').slideUp();
}
```